# Optimize elasticsearch query using highlighting

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight, elasticsearch-query

I would like to know why the processing time is increased when highlighting is used. Is there a way to optimize it?

An example query is mentioned below :

```
{
    "from": 30,
    "size": 60,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "shall have the right",
                    "fields": ["subType", "title", "type", "content"],
                    "fuzziness": 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "type": "unified",
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer, its been quite sometime ~1.5 years and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Because to get the highlight information, ES needs to run a fetch phase, which means another call.

Please read more about the fetch phase https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fetch_phase.html. Also in the same doc, information about the highlight is mentioned.

> The shard loads the document bodies—the _source field—and, if
>   requested, enriches the results with metadata and search snippet
>   highlighting. Once the coordinating node receives all results, it
>   assembles them into a single response that it returns to the client.